# NullPointer From Inside AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In the last couple of days, I've been getting this error in my logs and it does not emanate from any of my own written classes. Is it the same with other AppEngine users? What did I do wrong?

```
/_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages
java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.findServiceMethod(SystemService.java:232)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.resolveService(SystemService.java:209)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:132)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:106)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:438)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I am seeing the same

Comment: I learned to live with it since it doesn't affect my app :)

Comment: When I upgraded my app engine sdk to the latest version (1.8?), this went away

Comment: I"ve been going back and forth between 1.7.3 and 1.8.0. My Eclipse frequently complains that it can't detect AppEngine (so I switch again). I got tired of the whole thing yesterday so I'm migrating to another Eclipse (on another OS) so I should also be stable on 1.8.x very soon.

Comment: "My Eclipse frequently complains that it can't detect AppEngine" - make sure that your "appengine sdk library" is above any app engine jars on your eclipse classpath

Comment: @LawrenceTierney I get the /_ah/spi/BackendService error. I am using App Engine SDK 1.8.2 did the error come back.

Comment: @eddyparkinson - with sdk 1.8.1 I no longer see the error